# How to exit out of container shell from python cli

Tags: bash, shell, python, docker

I am running python within a container.

The goal is to exit out of the container from within the running python code after receiving the input
value `quit`. I tried the below code:

```
import subprocess

def qq():
    while True:
        choice = ""
        choice = input("Type \"quit\" to exit container> ")
        if choice == 'quit':
            print("Exiting container")
            subprocess.call("exit", shell=True)
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid input.")

qq()
```

After I `docker exec` and `bash` into the container, and run the above code, following is the output:

```
root@container:/pyScript#
root@container:/pyScript# python3 kwit.py
Type "quit" to exit container>
Invalid input.
Type "quit" to exit container> quit
Exiting container
root@container:/pyScript#
root@container:/pyScript#
```

Right now, the input `quit` takes me back to the container shell.

I would like the `quit` input to exit out of the my python's prompt and take me straight back to the docker host (instead of the container)

Comment: This doesn't work because you're starting a shell in the container, not your script. Set the entrypoint to be your python script, then the container should exit once the script exits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exec` when you run `python3`:

```
root@container:/pyScript# exec python3 kwit.py
```

That will replace the running shell with `python3` running that script.  When the `python3` process terminates, there's no more shell so the `docker exec` will terminate.